# How to show and hide div based on checkbox tick, but only a maximum of 3 showing at anyonetime

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want .company-01, .company-02 & .company-03 to show on load but then when the checkbox is ticked it only shows a maximum of 3 companies at anyone time. For example, 1, 2 and 3 show on load but when I tick checkbox 4 they all disappear and 4 shows. If checkbox 2 & 3 are then checked we would see company 02, 03 & 04 showing. If the user then clicks checkbox 01 then checkbox 04 is hidden as that was the earliest checked box.

I hope this makes sense?!?!

```js
var array = [];
$(".selector-checkbox").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    array.push(this.id);
    if (array.length > 3) {
      array.splice(0, 1);
    }
    $(".selector-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      $("#" + array[i]).prop("checked", true);
    }
  } else {
    var index = array.indexOf(this.id);
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

$('#company-01').click(function() {
  $('.company-01').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
$('#company-02').click(function() {
  $('.company-02').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});

$('#company-03').click(function() {
  $('.company-03').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});

$('#company-04').click(function() {
  $('.company-04').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});

$('#company-05').click(function() {
  $('.company-05').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="comparison-selector">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-01">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-02">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-03">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-04">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-05">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-06">

    </div>

    <div class="comparison-table">
      <div class="row row-flex">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">

          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 company-01">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 01</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-02">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 02</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-03">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 03</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-04">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 03</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Item 01</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, basically, start hiding all of them, and showing only selected ones.

```js
var array = [];
$(".selector-checkbox").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    array.push(this.id);
    if (array.length > 3) {
      array.splice(0, 1);
    }
    $(".selector-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      $("#" + array[i]).prop("checked", true);
    }
  } else {
    var index = array.indexOf(this.id);
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
  showHideCompanies();
});

function showHideCompanies() {
  $('.company').hide();
  $('.selector-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
     $('.' + this.id).show();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="comparison-selector">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-01">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-02">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-03">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-04">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-05">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-06">

    </div>

    <div class="comparison-table">
      <div class="row row-flex">
        <div class="col-sm-3 company company-01">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 01</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company company-02">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 02</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company company-03">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 03</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company company-04">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 04</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Item 01</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the initial input state and array to 1,2,3 companies.

```js
var array = ['company-01','company-02','company-03'];
$(".selector-checkbox").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    array.push(this.id);
    if (array.length > 3) {
      //Getting the deleted item id
      let deleteId = array.splice(0, 1)[0];
      //removing checked and active class
      $("#"+deleteId).prop("checked", false);
      $("."+deleteId).toggleClass('active', false);
    }
  } else {
    var index = array.indexOf(this.id);
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

$('.selector-checkbox').click(function() {
  let id = this.id; 
  $('.'+id).toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="comparison-selector">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-01" checked>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-02" checked>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-03" checked>
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-04">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-05">
      <input type="checkbox" class="selector-checkbox" id="company-06">

    </div>

    <div class="comparison-table">
      <div class="row row-flex">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">

          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 company-01">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 01</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-02">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 02</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-03">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 03</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 company-04">
          <div class="table-item table-header feature-box">
            <h2>Company 03</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 01</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 02</p>
          </div>
          <div class="table-item feature-box">
            <p>Feature 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Item 01</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Didn't got the question fully, added code for deleting .active class, when more than 3 items selected.

```
if (array.length > 3) {
  //Getting the deleted item id
  let deleteId = array.splice(0, 1)[0];
  //removing checked and active class
  $("#"+deleteId).prop("checked", false);
  $("."+deleteId).toggleClass('active', false);
}
```

**UPDATE2:** Optimezed js to handle checkbox click and change

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, the tickboxes do as they require and add/remove the 'active' class. However, when I check the 4th tickbox the 1st one hides (correct) but the 'active' state also remains  on the 1st checkbox despite not visible being active.